# Вывод таблицы через RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, redbeanphp

У меня такая проблема: есть бд, в которой есть таблица users, и мне нужно эту самую таблицу вывести, но выводится только слово 'Array' и больше ничего. Вот сам код:

### Все пользователи:

$query = R::findAll('users');
    echo($query);

Answer (score 1):

Вывести массив можно так:

```
print_r($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$table= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table);
echo $row['id']." ".$row['name']." ".$row['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

в RedBeanPHP надо передать  как минимум 2 параметра

```
    <?php
$ids = [3];// к примеру id таблицы 
$books = R::loadAll('user', $ids);
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->login.'<br>';  // login  вытаскиваем название по id
}
?>
```